# How to remove whitespace from a website by its element

Tags: html, css

I have this white space above between my image slideshow and stick nav bar header and I am not sure what is causing the gap. I have tried experimenting with different elements to set the padding and margin to 0 but cannot seem to remove that white space.

Below is the code with my experimental CSS:

```
/* Experiment padding and margin */
.post-inner{
    padding-top:0;
}

.header-footer-group {
   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide-content{
    padding-top:0;
    margin-top:0;
}

.menu-modal{
        padding-top:0;
    margin-top:0;
}

.menu-modal-inner{
        padding-top:0;
    margin-top:0;
}

media (min-width: 700px)
.post-inner {
    padding-top: 0;
}

/**/
```

I have provided a link to the website (it's only a single page) so you can inspect and have a look to see which element you think is causing it because I seem to be struggling in finding which element it could be:

[Website](https://axpsolutions.co.uk)

Comment: i selected the `article#post-2.post-2.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry` and set the `poition: absolute;` and `top: 60px` it solved the issue but i'm not sure if it's what you want or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white space seems to be caused by a `div` with the id of: `gutenslider-o6527m4ls`.
It has a top margin of *10rem* due to the rule:

```
.entry-content > .alignfull {
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
}
```

Setting the top margin of this div to zero should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. Really appreciate it as I spent over an hour on it and couldn't determine what set it. For fairness, I marked one as best answer and upvoted the other

Answer (score 2):

This rule causes it

```
@media ( min-width: 1220px ) {
/* ALIGNMENT CLASSES */

  .entry-content > .alignfull {
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. Really appreciate it as I spent over an hour on it and couldn't determine what set it. For fairness, I marked one as best answer and upvoted the other